# Websockify to wrap a forking server

Tags: javascript, postgresql, websocket, fork, rdbms

I came across Websockify [1] and the accompanying Websock client-side javascript library.

AIUI from the `Wrap a Program`section in README, Websockify can help you launch a TCP server and rebind its port so that incoming Websockets-based communication is parsed and forwarded to the server on the proper (rebinded) port.

My question is, can this mechanism be used to wrap a server that forks its children which in turn communicate with the client on a different port. Specifically, I am interested in websockifying a Postgres server, which typically listens on port 5432 and for a new incoming connection it forks a child which serves all future request from that client.

(If it helps, Oracle RDBMS and many other servers, RDBMS or not, also use similar method.)

[1] https://github.com/kanaka/websockify

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Pretty much all servers work by listening on a specific port and then accepting connections to a different port. Disclaimer: I made websockify.